# Strange behavior with the back button in Android when trying to get long presses

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I found a strange behavior in my Android application while trying to implement a long press catch event for the "back" button.

I use the following code for all the physical keys I want to manage in all of my activities (I removed unsignificant parts):

```
// Called when the user presses the "physical" buttons
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent aEvent)
{
    // Used to know which event was triggered
    int action = aEvent.getAction();
    int keyCode = aEvent.getKeyCode();

    // Get the pressed button
    switch (keyCode)
    {
        // Key "back"
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            // If the button is pressed down
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                // DEBUG
                App.debug("BACK button is pressed!");
            }
            // If the button is released
            else if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                // DEBUG
                App.debug("BACK button is released!");
            }
        return true;

        [...]

        default:
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(aEvent);
    }
}
```

The "App.debug()" method is only a wrapper for the "Log.d()" one.

When I test my code above, with a simple "tap" on the "back" button, I can see the expected lines to appear in the logcat ("BACK button is pressed!" when I touch the back button and "BACK button is released!" when I remove my finger).

Now when I keep my finger on the back button, I can ONLY see 2 times "BACK button is pressed!" to appear in the logcat, with aproximately half a second between them. Then when I release the button (say 10 seconds later) I see the "BACK button released!" sentence appearing as expected. Here is what I have in the logcat:

`BACK button is pressed!`  -> as soon as I touch the button with my finger

`BACK button is pressed!`  -> half a second later

`BACK button is released!` -> as soon as I remove my finger

Why does the "back" button long press ONLY triggers two "button down" events?

**EDIT:** I think I wasn't clear enough, sorry for this (English is not my natural language)... The problem is I ONLY have 2 events triggered as long as my finger remains on the button where it should trigger many many "button down" events until I remove my finger. Added "only" where it should be in my description.

**EDIT 2:** After some verification, it seems to only occur on some devices... Maybe Android version is involved here ?

"Not working as expected" tested devices are:

- Sony Xperia Z1 with Android 4.4.2
- Klipad Smart D71 with Android 4.4.2

"Working as expected" tested devices are:

- Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime with Android 4.4.4
- Huawei Y5 with Android 5.1.1

Any idea?

Have a nice day.

Comment: it will trigger as long as your finger remains on the back button. ACTION_DOWN also means "touching" and your finger is still touching. try holding down longer, and you'll see your log continually fire off.

Comment: if you aren't forced to manually design your own longpress for 'back', it is easier to use one of the existing methods.

Comment: well, as long as pressure is on the button it will trigger, so you could a add a second delay to check if the same flag will be triggered, then you move, so the prior/predecessor outputs you will ignore it.

Comment: I edited my problem as I was not clear enough. Sorry guys...

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of any KeyEvent changes between KitKat and Lollipop, nor do I have any 4.x devices to test with you. Sometimes, it is just slight modifications in the manufacturer's firmware/ASOP that affect these behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Two button_down events: 1 for the normal press, and 1 for the long press.

From Android 2.0, Activity contains the [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyLongPress(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent))

```
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

For exemple, a long key press on the back button would be :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
        // do your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

For normal click back button event. You can use:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to show dialog
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I edited my problem as I wasn't clear enough. Sorry for the trouble.